# Highstock time series navigator blank

Tags: time-series, highcharts

I have an Highstock time series chart,in this chart the time navigator is blank even if there is data.
[image: Navigator Blank]

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far? How are you assigning the data?

Comment: The navigator contains points from first serie, not sum all of them. But you can use separate serie for navigator, by assign. [Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series)

Comment: Yes, I think a separate series will solve the issue. How should I create the series for stacked chart navigator.?